# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.arangodb.ArangoDB$Builder Tomcat 9.0.4, Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I'm having `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arangodb.ArangoDB$Builder` error but not during compilation but on runtime.

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/arangodb/ArangoDB$Builder
    at dbmanager.ArangoDBManager.<init>(ArangoDBManager.java:12)
    at dbmanager.DbManager.createExercise(DbManager.java:296)
    at main.CreateProjectServlet.processRequest(CreateProjectServlet.java:34)
    at main.CreateProjectServlet.doPost(CreateProjectServlet.java:21)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arangodb.ArangoDB$Builder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
    ... 28 more
```

What I've read (and I've read a lot) it could be caused by missing class in runtime witch was present during compilation. That make sense a little but I did not found out how to solve it.

When I call the class (ArangoDBManager) from main in that class it works fine so problem must be on server.

I´am using Tomcat 9.0.4, Maven and Java 8.

My pom.xml:

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaEETomcat</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.45</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arangodb-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I`ve tried several versions of arangodb-java-driver but it did not help.

Class to handle ArangoDB:

```
import com.arangodb.ArangoDB;
import com.arangodb.entity.BaseDocument;

public class ArangoDBManager {
    private final ArangoDB arangoDB;
    static final String DB = "DP";
    static final String COLLECTION = "user_exercise_files";

public ArangoDBManager() {
    arangoDB = new ArangoDB.Builder().password("********").build();
}

public void insertDocument(BaseDocument document) {
    arangoDB.db(DB).collection(COLLECTION).insertDocument(document);
}

public void deleteDocument(String key) {
    arangoDB.db(DB).collection(COLLECTION).deleteDocument(key);
}

public BaseDocument getDocument(String key) {
    return arangoDB.db(DB).collection(COLLECTION).getDocument(key,
            BaseDocument.class);
}
```

Error is generating in constructor.

I have that class in classpath:[module dependecies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW2yL.png)

If I forget some info let me know.
I hope someone have some idea couse I feel like I already tried everything.

Comment: Update. I tried the Couchbase DB instead of Arango DB and problem is the same just can´t find "com/couchbase/client/java/document/Document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding .jar files to lib folder on Tomcat. Looks like it was caused by corrupted maven so clean install of maven should help too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change classpath scope for arangodb-java-driver to [Provided](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)